# Which icon image is used in Windows taskbar

Tags: windows-explorer

If a Windows application with a .ico icon is pinned to the Taskbar, how does Windows decide which image inside the .ico file to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icon resource named *IDR_MAINFRAME* within the project solution is typically used as the applications icon for the task bar.  However, you can easily [change](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/318/Replacing-the-Default-MFC-Icon) it to whatever you want.

Comment: But I won't know which one this is without source, correct?

Comment: That's correct.  Although you could try using a tool like [Resource Explorer](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Debuggers-Decompilers-Dissasemblers/Resource-Explorer.shtml) to peek into the contents of the executable or resource dll.